# R: Specify SSL version in Rcurl getURL statement

Tags: r, curl, ssl, rcurl

**Aim**
I am trying to write a statement to connect to a sharepoint online list to retrieve the data for use in R.

**Background**
This is my first time using RCurl/curl/libcurl and I've attempted to read the documentation but it's beyond me and doesn't have any relevant examples.

Using

```
a<-getURL("https://example.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Glossary")
```

Resulted in an error

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.sharepoint.com:443
```

A combination of google and deciphering of cryptic libcurl documentation identified that the issue was due to the SSL type.  I used curl in shell to verify and I got a positive response from the sharepoint server as a result (well, except the need to add the user name and password)

```
curl https://example.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Glossary -v -SSLv3
```

**Problem**
I cannot work out how to include the -SSLv3 argument in my getURL() function after RTFMs

**Requested solution**
Amend this statement to utilise SSLv3

```
a<-getURL("https://example.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Glossary")
```

Comment: Apologies to Duncan Temple Lang, but the RCurl documentation is a mess. You basically need to map the appropriate libcurl option ([see documentation here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)) to the relevant RCurl argument (see `listCurlOptions()` for all of the possible options). You probably want the `sslversion` argument. It's probably used as `sslversion="CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3"`, but you might have to play around with it a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the help - the line `sslversion="SSLVERSION_SSLv3"` when added is syntactically correct but doesn't seem to me helping.  Will keep plugging away but in the interim if you'd like to put it as an answer I can mark it as accepted

Comment: Well, if it doesn't solve the problem, then it's not a very good answer. :) Are you continuing to get the same error or is it something new?

Comment: Same error but I'm not sure if it's the same thing as the curl command get this message `< X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.`

Comment: That sounds like a server issue, not an **RCurl** issue.

Comment: If `curl https://example.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Glossary -v -SSLv3` works, then it sounds like an *RCurl* issue, not a server issue.

Comment: related question (to do not use SSLv3) asked on github repo: https://github.com/omegahat/RCurl/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
a<-getURL("https://example.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Glossary", ssl.verifypeer=TRUE, sslversion=4L)
```