# RCurl getURL SSL error

Tags: r, ssl, curl, rcurl, geturl

Related questions:

[RCurl errors when fetching ssl endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046176/rcurl-errors-when-fetching-ssl-endpoint)

[R: Specify SSL version in Rcurl getURL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237469/r-specify-ssl-version-in-rcurl-geturl-statement)

I am looking at the following:

```
url = https://www.veilingbiljet.nl/resultaten-ajax.asp?order=datum&direction=D&page=1&field=0&regio=39
```

Then,

```
getURL(url)
```

gives the following error:

```
error:1411809D:SSL routines:SSL_CHECK_SERVERHELLO_TLSEXT:tls invalid ecpointformat list
```

Adding the followinf curl option, suggested in one of the related questions,

```
getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = TRUE,sslversion=3L)
```

returns

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.veilingbiljet.nl:443
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The `RCurl` package is unmaintained and defunct. Use the `curl` package or `httr` instead:

```
library(curl)
con <- curl("https://www.veilingbiljet.nl/resultaten-ajax.asp?order=datum&direction=D&page=1&field=0&regio=39")
readLines(con)
```

Or:

```
library(httr)
req <- GET("https://www.veilingbiljet.nl/resultaten-ajax.asp?order=datum&direction=D&page=1&field=0&regio=39")
stop_for_status(req)
content(req)
```

Answer (score 4):

> error:1411809D:SSL routines:SSL_CHECK_SERVERHELLO_TLSEXT:tls invalid ecpointformat list

This is a [known bug](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2240&user=guest&pass=guest) in old OpenSSL versions and was fixed about 4 years ago. Thus upgrading your local OpenSSL should help.

If this is not possible you might disable the use of the affected ciphers by setting the [ssl.cipher.list](http://www.omegahat.net/RCurl/philosophy.html) option of RCurl to `HIGH:!ECDH`.

> Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.veilingbiljet.nl:443

The server does not support SSL 3.0 so trying to enforce this version will fail.