# Scraping from website using getURL() returns string of urls, not website content. How do I get the contents of the site? (R studio, windows 10)

Tags: r, web-scraping, windows-10, geturl

I am completely new to scraping, using Windows 10 PC. I am trying to run this code from class to scrape the content of the party platforms form the URLs below:

```
years=c(1968, 1972, 1976)
urlsR=paste("https://maineanencyclopedia.com/republican-party-platform-",
            years,"/",sep='')
urlsD=paste("https://maineanencyclopedia.com/democratic-party-platform-",
            years,"/",sep='')
urls=c(urlsR,urlsD)
scraped_platforms <- getURL(urls)
```

When I run "scraped_platforms" the result is what is shown below rather than the content of the party platforms from the website.

```
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/republican-party-platform-1968/ 
                                                             "" 
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/republican-party-platform-1972/ 
                                                             "" 
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/republican-party-platform-1976/ 
                                                             "" 
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/democratic-party-platform-1968/ 
                                                             "" 
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/democratic-party-platform-1972/ 
                                                             "" 
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/democratic-party-platform-1976/ 
                                                             ""
```

I've seen Windows 10 might be incompatible with getURL (re: [How to get getURL to work on R on Windows 10? [tlsv1 alert protocol version]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157670/how-to-get-geturl-to-work-on-r-on-windows-10-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)). Even after looking online though, I'm still unclear on how to fix my specific code?

List of links used here:

```
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/republican-party-platform-1968/
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/republican-party-platform-1972/ 
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/republican-party-platform-1976/
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/democratic-party-platform-1968/  
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/democratic-party-platform-1972/  
https://maineanencyclopedia.com/democratic-party-platform-1976/
```

Comment: Is `getURL()` a base function? If not, can you specify which package it's from?

Comment: It's from package RCurl @cory

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `getURL()` function, but in R, there is one very handy package for scraping: `rvest`

You can just use your `urls` object which has all URLs and loop over:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(Title= NULL,
             Text= NULL)
for (url in urls){
  t <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(".entry-title") %>% html_text2()
  p <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("p") %>%   html_text2()
  tp <- tibble(Title = t,
               Text = p)
  df <- rbind(df, tp)
}

df
```

This is a bit unorganized output, but you can adjust for loop so you can get it a bit nicer.

Here is also a bit nicer presentation of data:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Title) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  mutate(Text_all = paste0(Text, collapse = "\n")) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Text) %>%
  distinct()

df2
```